# SSH only detects 1 IP adress in my file.

Tags: bash, shell, centos7

Hi guys need help for my script. Concept of script is that it checks each docker server it that container is running. Docker server are saved in a file called 'ip' This is my sample script.

```
# !/bin/bash

function test2 {
  echo "Checking if qwer is running on $IP"


  isRunning=`ssh -tt root@$IP "docker inspect -f {{.State.Running}} qwer"`

  if [[ $isRunning ]]; then
     echo "Running on this server"

    else
     echo "[ INFO] Container is not running."
     echo $IP

  fi
}

function test1 {

  while read -r IP ; do

test2

   done < ip
}
test1
```

The File IP contains the following

192.168.21.61

192.168.21.64.

Problem is that only checks the first IP then stops already.

Sample output:

```
Checking if it is running on 192.168.21.61
Connection to 192.168.21.61 closed.
```

Comment: Put a `set -x` at the top of your script. This will request `bash` to output each line before execution and is an invaluable debugging aid.

Comment: Oh I see, Thanks for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will be considered closed,
I've actually replace my while statement to for loop.

```
for checkServer in $(cat $registeredServersFile); do  echo "Checking if qwer is running on $checkServer "; samfunc ; done
```